sudo still asks password after editing sudoers
I need to execute the command
ssh saroh@10.1.0.56 "sudo systemctl stop crs_svc"

in my GitLab YAML script. To do so I have updated the /etc/sudoers file on the host 10.1.0.56 and added the line
saroh ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl stop crs_svc

However, even when testing manually in the terminal I am geting
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

What could the problem possibly be? Thanks.
P.S. The OS on the servers is Oracle Linux.

Possibly this, then maybe this.

Thanks @KamilMaciorowski, the first link solved my problem.
